# How to use Drools backward chaining to list what initial facts are needed to satisfy a goal?

Tags: drools

I'm trying to use Drools backward chaining to find out which facts are needed to get an object inserted in the working memory. 
In the following example, I expect to get the fact "go2".

```
rule "ins a"
when
    String( this == "go2" )
then 
    insert(new A());
end


rule "Run"
when
then
    insert(new String("go1"));
end

rule "Test isThereAnyA"
    when
        String( this == "go1" )
        isThereAnyA(a;)
    then
        System.out.println( "you can get " + a );   
end

query isThereAnyA (A a)
    a := A()
end
```

I've been looking at examples in the official documentation
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e21289
but they show a different situation (the rules in those examples doesn't creates new fact)

From the chart
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e21240
I think it should work but I haven't found a way to specify a query that gives me the expected results.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

Unfortunately backward chaining can not be used for this purpose. 
It will not give you "go2" in this case.

Long answer:

In Drools, Backward chaining (BC) is a way to query the WM in a goal-driven fashion, not a way to trace back the derivation graph of a normal forward chaining inference process.

BC allows rule "Test" to retrieve As through the query "isThereAnyA", and possibly invoke other queries, but will not allow to find the "production" link between "A" and "go2". The reason is that "when..then..insert.." does not create any link between the triggering facts and the asserted conclusion, and backward chaining will not change it.

What you could do with BC is this:

```
query isThereAnyA_InPresenceOfA_String( A a )
   isThereAnyString( $s ; )       
   a := A()
end 
query isThereAnyString( String $s )
   $s := String( this == "go2" )
end
```

This will pick up As only if a String "go2" is (still) present. However you'll notice that the connection between a particular instance of A and a the particular String which led to its assertion is still missing.

To know exactly which objects led to the assertion of another object you may need a different approach. Options include:

- make the connection explicit : new A( $s ) // $s bound to "go2"
- use "insertLogical" to establish a dependency between "go2" and A, then query the TruthMaintenanceSystem

The TMS-based one would be my tentative choice, but it also depends on your exact requirements.

This use case is common, there may be other options, including a few which are experimental as they are being developed in 6.3, but I'd rather ask a few questions first.
That is: when do you need exactly to discover the facts - during the execution of the rules, or "offline"? Is it purely for auditing purposes, or does it impact your business logic? Can you have multiple rules asserting the "same" object?

Hope this helps
Davide

Comment: The use case is: the user inputs some desired state (goal) of the bussiness (ie, assigns a set of values to some POJOs).    
The rules are of the form: if the bussiness has X then it has Y  
I want to know which facts are needed to obtain Y, so I can advice the user: you should try to get X    

(I know that comments like "thanks" should be avoided, but I can't help it: thank you very much for your promptly answer)

Comment: So to answer your questions, I think I need to discover the facts "offline" (the rules may not even be executed). There isn't for auditing purposes, the results have impact the output of the system.
The last question is tricky: do you want me to have multiple rules asserting the "same" object? :D
I mean, I don't see where you are going, currently there are severals rules that assert the same object BUT
I have some control about this because there is a "name" attribute in the pojos that can be changed (moreover I'm using equalsBehavior="equality" so I can change the equals method).

Comment: If you feel REALLY adventurous, you can try something like this:
http://pastebin.com/YubQRE3w

In this particular (and experimental!!) flavor of backwward chaining, queries are allowed to insert objects if their conditions are satisfied. 
So, you start with a fact (Y) describing your state and the queries apply conditions and identify the possible preconditions (X). As X is asserted and connected to the instance of Y, you can eventually inspect the working memory and see the recommendations.

Notice that this is an unsupported and experimental feature which may change in the near future

Comment: I been investigating the abductive flavor of BC (I even made a tiny contribution to [AbductionTest.java](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/beliefsystem/abductive/AbductionTest.java) ) and I think that it may work _as long as_ I can automatically generate for each rule an abductive query that relates their pre and post conditions. Do you think it can be done? Can you give me some advice on how to do that?
I post [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596820/) with my advances in that direction.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the paired rule/query you'd like to write now? Thanks