# How to access to the consequence (RHS) of a rule from java?

Tags: java, drools

I have rules with the following structure:

```
rule "ins b"
when
    A()
then 
    B $b = new B();
    $b.setName("hello");
    insert($b);
end
```

I want to get the objects (and its attributes) that the rule adds to the working memory.
I'm able to get the LHS objects with the following code:

```
RuleImpl ri = (RuleImpl) kSession.getKieBase().getRule("com.sample", "ins b");
System.out.println("L: " + ri.getLhs());
Pattern rce = (Pattern) ri.getLhs().getChildren().get( 0 );
System.out.println("L: " + rce.getConstraints());
```

But I can't find something similar to obtain the RHS of the rule.

I want to do that because I'm trying to generate querys "automatically" based on rules.
From the above rule I want to generate something like:

```
query howToGetA() 
  @Abductive( target = A.class ) 
  $b := B( name == "hello" ) 
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? You "know" the object that's inserted as you write the code of the rule.

You can obtain the RHS by calling

```
RuleImpl ri = ...
Consequence cons = ri.getConsequence();
```

However, I don't think that this will give you "the objects (and its attributes) that the rule adds to the working memory". The consequence is code (in some form), and you won't find an *object* in that code, as the object is built at runtime.

Moreover, RuleImpl (and the interface Consequence and its implementations) are all part of the non-public API and subject to change without notice.

Comment: Possibly worth pointing out that, listeners can be implemented to see what objects are inserted by a rule, **when they are inserted**. Analyzing what objects could possibly be inserted by a rule only seems relevant to someone implementing a rules engine themselves. Especially given that a rule might invoke a method on a Java class, which itself performs inserts...

Comment: @Steve Granted - much (more) can be pointed out, but on spec? That's why I started with "Why".

Comment: @laune You are right about RuleImpl; Eclipse even gives a warning "Discouraged access: The type 'RuleImpl' is not API ..." But I couldn't think of another way to achieve the generation of a query based on a rule. Thank you for your valuable comments and I'm sorry not being more clear initially to ask the question.

Comment: @Steve As you pointed out, using listeners I can get what objects are inserted when the rule is fired, but I want to extract the information without fire the rules. Maybe, I will have to parse drl files...

Comment: Unfortunately, to date, the RHS is a "black box". It is parsed as a Java String, compiled on the fly and executed as such.
We have been talking about "@Logical" rules, with a restricted RHS syntax and some predefined semantics for Drools 7
Right now, I'd recommend to use an annotation on the rule to declare what kind of class it asserts, and be consistent in allowing the RHS of that rule to *just* instantiate and insert an instance of that object

Comment: Can someone give me a link to the description of what the RHS is?